# Nested for loop  - 1D indexing

Tags: c++, 2d

```
//The size of test doesn't matter for now just assume it's fitting
int* test = new int[50000]
    for(int i=stepSize;i<=maxValue;i+=stepSize){

               for(int j=0;j<=i;j+=stepSize){
                    //Comput something and store it
                    test[i*30+j] = myfunc();
               }

    }
```

If I now would want to convert it in a 1D array how could I calculate the correct indices for the 1D array? For example for i=5 and j=0 it should be at the first posistion etc.

EDIT: Updated the code. I tried to calculate something and store it in a 1d array by calculating its index with i*30+j but this doesnt work.

Comment: What did you try? Also, the code sample presented makes no sense to me. It doesn't help at all.

Comment: I updated the sample. Basically I want to compute some values inside the nested for loop and than store the results in a 1D array from 0 to n.

Comment: Why do you start iterating `i` at 5? How did you declare the array?

Comment: Basically the for loop is dynamic so I start at some value increment it to some maxValue in steps of stepSize (updated the code)

Comment: Alright, but where is the 2D array you're talking about?

Comment: Okay. my mistake. Just forget about the 2d array then ... :)

Comment: Sorry, but this still doesn't make any sense. You've got 1D array and you want to index it continuosly, 0,1,2,3...? What's with the `stepSize` then? Why this weird iteration? What problem are you solving? You should take your time and explain it better if you want helpful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the array was defined as follows:

```
int a[30][5];
```

you could index into it like this:

```
a[i][j]
```

Or define it as a 1 dimension array as follows:

```
int a[30*5];
a[j + 5*i];
```

Here is an example program that displays the iterations:

(Notice that there are those who might say I switched the rows and columns, but it doesnt really matter since its iterating contiguously through the array. That is if you think of the rows and columns differently, just switch all occurrences and you should get the same result.)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int columns = 30;
    int rows = 5;
    int a[columns*rows]; // not really needed for this example

    for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
        {
            cout << "[" << i << "][" << j << "] offset: " << (i*rows + j)
                 << endl;
        }
    }
}

[0][0] offset: 0
[0][1] offset: 1
[0][2] offset: 2
[0][3] offset: 3
[0][4] offset: 4
[1][0] offset: 5
[1][1] offset: 6
[1][2] offset: 7
[1][3] offset: 8
[1][4] offset: 9
[2][0] offset: 10
[2][1] offset: 11
[2][2] offset: 12
[2][3] offset: 13
[2][4] offset: 14
[3][0] offset: 15
[3][1] offset: 16
[3][2] offset: 17
[3][3] offset: 18

...

[27][4] offset: 139
[28][0] offset: 140
[28][1] offset: 141
[28][2] offset: 142
[28][3] offset: 143
[28][4] offset: 144
[29][0] offset: 145
[29][1] offset: 146
[29][2] offset: 147
[29][3] offset: 148
[29][4] offset: 149
```

And one more piece of information, if you need to allocate a 2D array dynamically, here's how:

```
int **a = new int*[30];
for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    a[i] = new int[5];
}
```

Comment: The `i` in the multiplication is wrong - you'd like the number of elements in one row (or column depending on order) instead.

Comment: This does not work as the computed index i+i*j will be 5, 12, 24 etc. but I want it to store the values continously on positions 0,1,2 etc.

Comment: even with j+5*i it won't give me a continous indexing

Comment: @user1356695, sorry for the delay, I just got back from lunch, I updated the answer with more info.